# Converting comma delimited items to an entity using edmx

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model, ef-database-first

Is it possible to convert the column (stored as comma delimited) to be presented in the edmx designer as another entity?

table structure

```
student
  id
  name
  subjects << this is the comma delimited column (1,2,3,10)

subject
  id
  name
```

EDMX designer structure would be

```
student 
  id
  name

student_subject
  studentId
  subjectid

subject
  id
  name
```

If so, can someone point me on how to do it on EF designer.

NOTE: I cannot change the table structure and I'm using database first

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Worse: in SQL it might be possible to fetch the subjects with an `IN` clause, but with linq you haven't even got that option. I'm afraid what's left is a painstaking linq-to-objects operation where you first grab the `Student` from the database, then parse the subjects in an `int` array, and finally grab the `Subject`s with a `Contains` query:

```cs
var subjectIds = student.Subjects
    .Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select (x => int.Parse(x));

var subjects = context.Subjects.Where(s => subjectIds.Contains(s.Id));
```

(And don't forget to send the architect as student to a course with subject 'Data base design')